# Can I make a PDF to expire after a specific date

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to know some extra security tips in dealing with PDF files. I found that we can easily make a PDF file password protected using `pdftk` command from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258848/is-there-a-tool-that-can-add-a-password-to-a-pdf-file).

**But is it possible to make PDF files to expire after a specific date?**

I mean a PDF displayable only for a particular period of time and after that if someone tries to open it he would get only a message like "Sorry, nothing to display".

Is there any command or script for that?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any command or script for that?

[Here](https://www.evermap.com/JavaScriptSecurity.asp) is an example of applying extra security checks. You can put in a bit of  extra javascript in your pdf that closes the file when a certain date has passed. Some issues ...

- it won't work if javascript is turned off
- it does not prevent opening the file when a user chances the systems date
- it does not prevent the user making printscreens

So it is seriously flawed. All it takes is 1 person with a bit of knowledge to circumvent your check. See [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/882036) for more on that.

The link also lists as alternatives for a DRM server: http://www.fileopen.com (3000 usd a year) and http://www.locklizard.com/  (5k for a perpetual license) (...).

---

You did not list why you wanted this but consider an alternative: google doc with a read only file. And you remove the file when your date has passed.