# Is there a scanning program that creates pdf files with password protection?

Tags: 16.04, pdf, scanner

Could someone tell me if a **scanning program exists that writes pdf files with password** protection, please?

Before posting this question I tried Simple Scan, XSane Image scanning program, gscan2pdf and Scan Tailor. It's not possible to set a password for pdf files.

Comment: This is good thread about that [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258848/is-there-a-tool-that-can-add-a-password-to-a-pdf-file)

Comment: @salesh Thanks for your link. PDF Chain works. Saving a scanned document in pdf file format with a password directly from a scanning software would be even more comfortable. Is there such a scanning application?